# React.js two-way binding for two different inputs in one function

Tags: reactjs, two-way-binding

Can I make two-way binding for two different inputs in one function?

In order to bind:

```
 <Input  placeholder='title...' onChange={this.handelChangetitle.bind(this)} />
 <textarea className='textarea' onChange={this.handelChangecontent.bind(this)}>d</textarea>
```

to:`<p>Blog title:{this.state.title}</p>
   <p>Blog content:{this.state.content}</p>`

I need two very similar functions:

```
handelChangetitle(event){this.setState({title:event.target.value})}
handelChangecontent(event){this.setState({content:event.target.value})}
```

Is any way I can save some code,only use one functions but bind 'title' and 'content' at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a single function like this:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

And then add a name attribute to your input and textArea tags, like this:

```
<Input name='title' placeholder='title...' onChange={this.handleChange} />
<textarea name='content' className='textarea' onChange={this.handleChange}>d</textarea>
```

Comment: This is beautiful!But when I code like this:handleChange (e) {
   this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}   It also works,and save more code.Is this way right also?

Comment: All this part: handleChange = (e) => basically does is it takes care of the binding for you behind the scenes so you don't have to do it manually

Comment: So you should keep it unless you are manually binding because otherwise you will get errors in your console and it will not update your state value because 'this' context will be lost

Answer (score 2):

Add a name prop to the inputs

```
<input 
  name="title" 
  onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
  value={this.state.title}
/> 

<textarea
  name="content" 
  onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
  value={this.state.content} 
/>
```

Then you will be able to retrieve it in your handler function

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target
  this.setState({ [name]: value })
}
```

Comment: It works very well!This is beautiful!But when I code like this:handleChange (e) {
   this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}   It also works,and save more code.Is this way right also?

Comment: Sure it is, it's just a stylistic difference and I prefer it like that. Btw, it's called object destructuring.